# How can I load the standard wireless driver after I deinstall ndiswrapper?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel

since I have some problems with my download speed under ubuntu (see my other question) I installed ndiswrapper to load windows driver for my wifi card. Unfortunatly it didn't worked very well so I deinstalled ndiswrapper. But now in network-manager-applet the option to connect wifi is also gone.

How can I load the standard wifi driver or even better how can i activate the wireless backports driver so that it works with network-manager-applet?

I found an advice via google to use sudo modprobe wl but this gives the message FATAL: Module wl not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to use modprobe with the right modulename
so if anyone has the problem use:

```
sudo modprobe yourmodulenameforyourwificard
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your hardware's driver isn't blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/*.  It would appear with "blacklist " prepended on a line, e.g., "blacklist wl" (if your driver is wl).  Secondly, installing `linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic` should suffice after a reboot (provided that the appropriate driver isn't blacklisted **and** that you're using 10.10/Maverick).

Comment: i don't find something like wl blacklisted in the /etc/modprobe.d/ folder. but i'm not sure if wl is exactly the name of my driver since i found the advice (modproble wl in a forum). How can i recognize what's the name of my driver i used before? I installed the backports drivers, but after a reboot there is now wifi device in iwconfig.

Comment: update: i found the module name of my wifi and now it works as it should. the only limitation is i'm using not the latest kernel at the moment. cause i switched back. how can i verify which driver the card use (backports? version) so that i can check if i use the right one under the latest kernel?